# App crashes after adding latest Firebase dependency

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My android app crashes after adding Firebase latest dependencies

Dependencies I'm using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.3'
```

My Error logs

```
2021-08-07 14:23:23.169 23119-23119/? E/pp.firebasetes: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-08-07 14:23:24.760 23119-23119/app.firebasetest W/pp.firebasetes: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory;->metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; (blacklist, linking, denied)
2021-08-07 14:23:24.760 23119-23119/app.firebasetest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-08-07 14:23:24.768 23119-23119/app.firebasetest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.firebasetest, PID: 23119
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discoverLazy(ComponentDiscovery.java:112)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:418)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2102)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2076)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6934)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6851)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:242)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7822)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
2021-08-07 14:23:24.831 23119-23119/app.firebasetest I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23119 SIG: 9
```

Not only firestore dependency, if I add any latest firebase dependency my app crashes on launch.

Testing on real devices with version 10.

My android studio Google Play Service SDK is installed and upto date(version 49).

My android studio version is 4.0

But if I add old dependencies It's working fine.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
```

But I want the latest versions of firebase dependencies to use in my app. what's going wrong with me? can any one please tell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these lines inside the app level `build.gradle`

```
 android {
    
        ...
        // ADD THESE LINES
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
    }
```